# Prove by induction that $n+\cos(n) \leq 2^n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Having a little trouble with this one because of the $\cos(n+1)$ when you assume $P(n)$ to be true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Can you prove that $n + 1 \le 2^n$?

Comment: why does this even need induction ?

Answer (score 2):

You can, if you like, try a straightforward induction, using the angle addition formula.  Starting with something that's not quite right, the inductive step is

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)+\cos(n+1)&=(n+1)+(\cos n\cos1-\sin n\sin1)\\
&=(n+\cos n\cos1)+(1-\sin n\sin1)\\
&\le(n+\cos n)+2\quad\text{(except there's a problem here, discussed below)}\\
&\le2^n+2^n\\
&=2^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

The problem is, the inequality $n+\cos n\cos1\le n+\cos n$ is not always true. What we really need to do, to make this approach work, is to prove a "stronger" inequality, $n+|\cos n|\le2^n$. The correct inductive step is

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)+|\cos(n+1)|&=(n+1)+|\cos n\cos1-\sin n\sin1|\\
&\le(n+|\cos n\cos1|)+(1+|\sin n\sin1|)\\
&\le(n+|\cos n|)+2\\
&\le2^n+2^n\\
&=2^{n+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Beware that $sin(n)$ can be negative which indicates separate cases.

Comment: @Idle, it's actually the $\cos n$ that causes trouble here.  I was edited when your comment came in.

Comment: @BarryCipra I have repaired my proof. Can you please cancel the downvote?

Comment: @Raffaele, I did not downvote your answer. I'll delete my comment, which is no longer relevant. Unfortunately your answer is still problematic, since the inequality $n+1+n+1\lt n+\cos n+n+\cos n$, which amounts to $1\lt\cos n$, is clearly wrong! (Please ping me after you've seen this, so we can delete what amounts to a chat.)

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the fundamental facts of mathematics that $\# A<\#{\cal P}(A)$. This immediately implies $n+\cos(n)\leq n+1\leq 2^n$ for all $n\geq0$.